# Control one Kafka Stream from another

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, observer-pattern

The set up I have is:

- 3 topics: inputTopic, outputTopic and commandTopic.
- 2 KStreams, one read from inputTopic, do some processing the write to outputTopic. The other stream listen on the commandTopic and if a command msg comes by, I want this stream to register some sort of call back to the processing stream. The processing stream meant to stop and reinitialise with a different filter definition (the new definition is a payload in the command message).

I am not sure if there is a design pattern to follow when one stream register a call back that tells the other stream to reinitialise. I can think of the observer pattern which I can have a controller to manage both stream, then the command stream can do a call back to the controller which then stops and reinitialise the processing stream. Is this the right approach or is there a better/recommended way to achieve this goal.

Comment: Unless you expect multiple streams (to be controlled in future), controller seems to be an over-engineering. I would go by having two streams : the command stream which will control the processing stream directly. One question I do have is how will you pass the updated filter to the processing stream?

Comment: With the Observer pattern, in the callback I would just pass the string object that I pull from the commandTopic to the controller then it can use that to initialise. 

So with your suggestion on having the command stream control the processing stream. Can you elaborate on that?  I am not sure how to set it up actually, command stream reads command topic and initialise the processing stream that reads input topic?

Comment: I don't think a stream application can read from a message and update it's logic on its own. For the filter to be processed you would have to stop the processing stream and restart it. I would say store the filter config in a known location (Shared location/DB/service) which is accessible to both command and processing streams. But the restarting of the processing stream would need to be done outside Kafka Streams. Since you cannot restart a Streams application that is stopped, you would have to launch a new process